How can i make my second form open right?
When i run my program the second form opens for only half a second. I'm new to coding and especially new to c#. My objective is to have a list view where i can add "Goods" and "Suppliers" with an Add Button.
One of the 2 add forms
Main Form
//Code from MainForm.cs
namespace Supply_business.Forms
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public Contracts Contract;
        public MainForm()
        {
            Contract = new Contracts();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DisplayContent()
        {
            lsview2.Items.Clear();
            Contract.Goods.Sort();
            lsview1.Items.Clear();
            Contract.Suppliers.Sort();
            foreach (var supplier in Contract.Suppliers)
            {
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(supplier.Name);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(supplier.Email);
                lvi.Tag = supplier;
                lsview1.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
            foreach (var good in Contract.Goods)
            {
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(good.Name);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(good.Description);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(good.Price.ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(good.Quantity.ToString());
                lvi.Tag = good;
                lsview2.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
        }

        private void AddBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddEditContract addEditContract = new AddEditContract();
            Good good = new Good();
            addEditContract.thisGood = good;

            if (addEditContract.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Contract.Goods.Add(good);
                DisplayContent();
            }
        }

        private void AddBtn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddEditSuppliercs addEditSuppliercs = new AddEditSuppliercs();
            Supplier supplier = new Supplier();
            addEditSuppliercs.thisSupplier = supplier;

            if (addEditSuppliercs.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Contract.Suppliers.Add(supplier);
                DisplayContent();
            }
        }
    }
}

// Code from AddEditSuppliers

    public partial class AddEditSuppliercs : Form
    {
        public Supplier thisSupplier { get; set; }
        public AddEditSuppliercs()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AddEditSuppliercs_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (thisSupplier != null)
            {
                txtName.Text = thisSupplier.Name;
                txtEmail.Text = thisSupplier.Email;

                Close();
            }
        }

        private void Okbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (thisSupplier != null)
            {
                thisSupplier.Name = txtName.Text;
                thisSupplier.Email = txtEmail.Text;

                Close();
            }
        }
    }
}


You have a Close in OnLoad. Try to debug and see if that isn't the culprit.

That was the problem, thank you!

Calling close() is equivalent to clicking the close button (x) on the form's title bar or calling the Dispose() method. It has no reason to be on the Form_Load event. Also, it is a good pratice to open the child forms as modal dialog. Also, Make sure you wrap it in the using statement. This will ensure that the form is properly disposed and memory is freed.
